# How can I loop sleep/hibernate/reboot/cold boot for testing in Ubuntu?

Tags: power-management

I would like to test the system stability on power management, like reboot system for 500 times and see if it unresponsive or failed to reboot.

It's easy to do this in Windows using pwrtest, but I don't have any idea of how to do it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @abu_bua I "improved" your edit since you made some useful punctuation changes and a judicious paragraph break, but please do not add bold for emphasis to random parts of other people's posts. It's really uncomfortable for reading. Please see for example [this meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17842/where-to-use-blockquotes-pre-formatted-text-and-bold/17843#17843)

Answer (score 1):

One idea: write some code in /etc/rc.local that keeps a counter in a file and, as long as the counter hasn't reached 500, calls `reboot`.
You'll want to be careful about the location of the file - it needs to survive the reboot, so don't put it in /tmp.
It may also be a smart idea to only call `reboot` if the counter file exists so you can break out of the reboot loop by booting a live Linux and removing the counter file.

Comment: You can always remove the file from a live session or from grub rescue if needed ;)